# why won't VScode compile the function strtok proprely?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, null, strtok

I started working on VS Ccode recently and I want to use the function `strtok()` for my project but it won't <s>compile</s> run properly.
I tried compiling this function in an online compiler and it works so apparently the issue is with VScode.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? And does anyone have a solution to my problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *base(char *line){ 
    
    char *base, *dividedline;
    const char s[3] = " ";

    //get the first token
    dividedline = strtok(line,s);
    printf("%s\n", dividedline);
    //get the others
    for(int i; i!=3;i++){ 
        dividedline = strtok(NULL,s);
        printf("%s\n", dividedline);
        if(i == 2){ 
            base = dividedline;
        }
        return dividedline;
    }
    printf("finished");
    return base;

}

int main()
{
    printf("hello world \n");
    char *l;
    char str[80] = "hi  test    test";
    l = base(str);

    return 0;
}
```

The function is stuck on an infinite loop when I compile it with VScode.
I know the issue is with the line "dividedline = strtok(NULL,s);" and especially with the NULL, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Having a variable called `base` inside a function called `base` is unorthodox and potentially confusing.  Avoid that sort of accident.  (OTOH, it has nothing to do with your problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the line:

```
for(int i; i!=3;i++)
```

You don't know what the initial value of `i` is.  You should have written:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 3; i++)
```

A more defensive style of programming would use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Your loop could still take a long time if `i` was initialized negative, but would stop immediately if `i` was positive and bigger than 3.  The `<` idiom is normal in C.

Comment: oh my god i feel so stupid  for forgetting that, thank you so much